# Problem with reciprocal document referencing in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've looked everywhere to find a way for referencing documents reciprocally in Mongoose. But all documentation including [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) only have examples that save objectID of one document in another. Consider that I have a parent document ("category") and multiple child documents ("subcategories") and I want to reference the parent inside the children and vice versa. How can I do so?

The last thing that came to my mind was to add objectID references before saving the documents to the database. Here's the code for that:

Category Schema:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose")


let categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    sale_type: String,
    sub_categories: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 
    "SubCategory" }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema)
```

Subcategory Schema:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose")

let subcategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    sale_type: String,
    category: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("SubCategory", subcategorySchema)
```

Main file: (This route is intended for making new "Categories")

```
app.post("/categories", function(req, res){
    let name = req.body.name
    let sale_type = req.body.sale_type
    let sub_categories = req.body.sub_categories.split(",")
    let category = new Category({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: name,
        sale_type: sale_type,
        sub_categories: []
    })
    sub_categories.forEach(function(element){
        let sub_category = new SubCategory({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name: element,
            sale_type: sale_type,
            category: category._id
        })
        sub_category.save(function(err, subcat){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send("")
            } else {
                category.sub_categories.push(subcat._id)
            }
        })
    })
    category.save(function(err, cat){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("")
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(cat)
        }
    })
})
```

The awkward thing that happens is that when I hit the "/categories" route to make a new category, this is the response that I get from the server which is exactly what I want:

```
{
    "sub_categories": [
        "5c2340bf4641017050567fe8",
        "5c2340bf4641017050567fea"
    ],
    "_id": "5c2340bf4641017050567fe6",
    "name": "cat",
    "sale_type": "retail",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But when I use mongo shell to look for categories, here's what is actually saved in the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2340bf4641017050567fe6"), "sub_categories" : [ ], 
"name" : "cat", "sale_type" : "retail", "__v" : 0 }
```

and the sub_categories array is empty!!!

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions, and here is my opinion on the first, concerning reciprocally referencing documents:

Unless you know that there is a rather small, finite amount of subcategories, don't use an array to store references. If subcategories can grow without bound, you might run into problems with performance later on. (e.g. see [this](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/) article for more information)

Since mongoose 4.5 there is a great feature called "virtual populate" which I think is a more elegant solution to your problem. For this, you can simply create a virtual field in your category, that'll automatically fetch the array of subcategories for it like this:

```
// a `ref` property is how you enable virtual population
Category.virtual('subcategories', {
  localField: '_id',
  ref: 'Subcategory',
  foreignField: 'category'
});
```

If used like this, there will be no actual field saved in the Category collection, but if you query the doc properly, you'll be able to use it just the same, without the problems of saving arrays of references:

```
Category.find().populate('subcategories')
```

There is a great article about that topic here: http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate

This should also solve (or at least workaround) your second problem, since the field is not being persisted to the db anymore. Why it is not displaying the data I don't know, but I believe you should be able to debug this by adding first verifying that the correct data was written to the db in your code (e.g. before returning the data, run a `Category.find()` to ensure that you actually updated the DB and not only return a stale object, that wasn't persisted to the db). If you are really interested in why this is happening, think about creating a new, more specific question only for this problem with a minimal problem code.